# Match a field in datagridviewcombobox as in the combobox items collection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

Need a small help with  datagridview's comboboxcolumn. I already have a column 'vat_percent' and its dataproperty name to 'vat_per'. I have few items in a items list(manually set). So, when I load data from a database with the columname 'vat_per', it gives me a dataerror message even if the values in itemslist matches with the data from the database. How can I solve this problem?

thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't think they match each other. You should be sure they also match in `data type`.

Comment: What about your `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn's DisplayMember and ValueMember`? You should provide more code.

Comment: i've set display member and value member to same 'vat_percent'

Comment: the data types should also be matched, you should check that.

Comment: How can I do it? I can't fix the problem even after trying for long time.

Comment: I can only help you if you describe your problem better (such as with code), how you initialize DataSource for your DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, what is the underlying DataSource of your DataGridView, ...